# JAVASCRIPT pop up box display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my html:

```
<div class="popup" onclick="itemPopup()">

    <img src="{{$item->item->img}}">
    <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">

    {{$item->title}}<br> 
    <a href="/sell-item/{{$item->id}}" class="btn-sm btn-danger" style="text-decoration: none">
    Sell for {{$item->price/2}} <img src="/img/gold.png"></a><br>
    <p>{{$item->description}}</p>

    </span> 
</div>  
@endforeach
```

This is my js:

```
function itemPopup() {
    var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
    popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

When I click on image the pop up shows like this:

[image]

No matter if I click on second sword, the pop up box will still appear on first sword with his `id`. How to fix this issue ?

Comment: Share your css too, better you share a live demo. i know what's your problem but without a live demo with css and js can't help

Comment: @pedram there is no css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign unique ids to each iteration of your blade and then pass that same ID in the JavaScript function call. Your HTML will look like this.

```
<div class="popup" onclick="itemPopup('myPopup{{$item->id}}')">

    <img src="{{$item->item->img}}">
    <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup{{$item->id}}">

    {{$item->title}}<br> 
    <a href="/sell-item/{{$item->id}}" class="btn-sm btn-danger" style="text-decoration: none">
    Sell for {{$item->price/2}} <img src="/img/gold.png"></a><br>
    <p>{{$item->description}}</p>

    </span> 
</div>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
function itemPopup(ID) {
    var popup = document.getElementById(ID);
     popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

Comment: `<span class="popuptext" id="{{$item->id}}">` how to grab span id now ?

Comment: Edited my answer to include the HTML. I assign a unique id to each iteration and then pass it in the JavaScript call

Comment: What to write now in ID ?

Comment: The code I wrote should work. ID is a variable being passed by the clicked element